# Nuxt (and Webpack): How to separate a single JS file to be reused by external app?

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

I've stumbled upon several pages about importing external files into a Nuxt project, but what I'm trying to do is the opposite.

I have two sites or apps: Site A and Site B. Site A is the main one built using Nuxt. Site B is a simple site with static pages, not using Nuxt or Vue.

Site A has a JavaScript file, let's say its path is  `/lib/common.js`. I use it extensively on Site A. And I also want to use it on Site B.

However, when I do `yarn generate` on Site A, all my JS files, including `common.js`, get bundled into a JavaScript chunk files, and each file is named with a hash of the content of the file. For example, `/lib/common.js`, `/lib/util.js` get bundled up as `/dist/_nuxt/05443d2eb25fc282bbea.js` while `/lib/user.js` is bundled as `/dist/_nuxt/1326d0fc90870f9f4ca4.js`.

That means:

1. the file I want to use is actually bundled with other files into the same package, so if I load that file, I have to load extra code with it and,
2. I can't really predict the name of that file.

Is there a way for me to tell Nuxt, or most likely Webpack, to single out `/lib/common.js` into its own bundle and then save it as `/dist/_nuxt/lib/common.js` instead of a hash, so the filename is more predictable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a separate webpack configuration for that single file to achieve the desired result as only one output configuration per configuration file is supported[0].

[0] https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#output

Example common library configuration `common.lib.config.js`

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './lib/common.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/_nuxt/lib'),
    filename: 'common.js'
  }
};
```

And build it with `webpack --config common.lib.config.js`

Comment: Yup, that's the route I also took yesterday. I think that's the best way to do it too. Thanks!